# Using jOOQ, how to generate only specific members of a package?

Tags: code-generation, jooq

I am trying to avoid generating code for stored procedures that I don't need.
The relevant part of the generator config (maven plugin) looks like this:

```
<includes>
    SOME_SCHEMA\.SOME_PACKAGE\.MyProcedure
</includes>
<excludes></excludes>
```

Unfortunately, this does not match anything. Using

```
<includes>
    SOME_SCHEMA\.SOME_PACKAGE
</includes>
```

works, but of course generates the code for the whole package.

*MyProcedure* is the exact case-sensitive name for the procedure as defined in the database. I have also tried using

```
SOME_SCHEMA\.SOME_PACKAGE\.MYPROCEDURE
```

,without success.

Edit - research: I have looked at the jOOQ manual section on [code generation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual-single-page/#code-generation), but have not found a solution to my problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `<includes>` and `<excludes>` match packages only, not procedures / functions / types contained in packages. More accurately, the regular expressions match schema-level objects.

There's an existing flag to extend this behaviour to columns in tables (using `<includeExcludeColumns/>`), but as of jOOQ 3.9, no such flag exists for objects inside of packages

I've created a feature request to implement this in a future jOOQ version:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6400

#### Workarounds:

- You could extend the `org.jooq.util.oracle.OracleDatabase` and `org.jooq.util.oracle.OraclePackageDefinition` in jOOQ-meta to filter out those procedures that you're not interested in.
- You could override the `JavaGenerator.generatePackage()` method in jOOQ-codegen to prevent the code generation of unwanted objects
- You could post-process the generated code and remove unwanted objects and references to those objects again.